# AngularJS e2e testing in Rails stack: [object Object] has no method 'resumeBootstrap'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, karma-runner

It seems quite hard to get the AngularJS/Karma end-to-end testing environment working with a Rails backend.

I have Karma installed and running with the following config file:

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

// singleRun = true;

proxies = {
  '/': 'http://local.mywebsite.com:3000/'
};

urlRoot = 'e2e';

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

Where http://local.mywebsite.com:3000/ is my rails application.

I try a very simple test:

```
it('should redirect to /', function() {
  expect(browser().location().url()).toBe("/");
});
```

But I am stuck with the following error:

```
http://localhost:9876/base/test/e2e/scenarios.js:8:5

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resumeBootstrap'
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:26285:27)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:3064:9)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.elemData.handle.eventHandle (http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:2682:28)
    at k (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:48:745)
```

Where scenarios.js comes from https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Just for Your information. This error indicates that app bootstrapping process is deferred. You can read about it at following link at the bottom of the page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap. Angular-scenario (e2e tests) use deferred bootstrapping for application being tested. Maybe You somewhere modify window.name so that NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! flag is erased? Please note that angular-scenario loads app in an iframe, so You've got to debug scripts of that app.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
it('should redirect to /', function() {
  browser().navigateTo("/");
  expect(browser().window().path()).toBe("/");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would get the most up-to-date version of angular scenario runner. You can find the unstable version at

```
http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular-scenario.js
```

and the stable version at

```
http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular-scenario.js
```

Then, be sure to update your karma configuration to use the newest scenario runner

```
files = [
    'path/to/angular-scenario.js',
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
    'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes! Finally, it was a case of commenting out Karma's `ANGULAR_SCENARIO` and using `angular-scenario.js` relative to the framework version!

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is correct. This link covers the problem: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/470

I hit the same issue while running the excellent examples on: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-testacular.html

That's a great resource if you're getting started, but you will need to update from testacular to karma and update angularjs to 1.0.6